# Failed to load resource for Images in Chrome

Tags: java, php, image, tomcat

I am facing a weird problem just in chrome. I am getting an image from server which works fine in Firefox, but in chrome the image loads for once and then it shows as broken image.

In console of Chrome I am getting the following message :

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://46.137.249.133:8080/Smart/Request/query.htm?ReqType=SessionUnawareAttachmentDownloadReqType&Thumbnail=Yes&AttachmentRowID=344929138455741006"
GET http://46.137.249.133:8080/Smart/Request/query.htm?ReqType=SessionUnawareAttachmentDownloadReqType&Thumbnail=Yes&AttachmentRowID=344929138455741006
```

I also checked the mime type, but its image/jpeg. Here is the output of `getimagesize()`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 289
    [1] => 202
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="289" height="202"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

Comment: getimagesize may look into the data, not into the http header. You need to have a correct content type there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the output from `curl --verbose <your-url>` and you can see that you web server (on port 8080) is advertising the file as `text/html`.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
[...]
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Hall2.JPG"
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

You can fix this by setting the correct Media Type by adding a `Content-Type` header line to each HTTP response.

In PHP, do it using `header` function, like:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

It's very similar for a Java Servlet page:

```
HttpServletResponse res;
res.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

Comment: I cant add `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` cause the server is coded in JAVA, can I do something inside my PHP file?

Comment: It's very similar to do so in Java. I've added the command to my response.

Answer (score 1):

In query.html, before you output anything (ideally, at the very beginning of your script), add:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

It will tell your browser that the content returned is a JPEG image.

Comment: I ll need to add this in server? Is their any other way which I can put this in my .php file because these images are coming from java not from PHP

Comment: your question is tagged as PHP, I am therefore giving a PHP answer.

Comment: sorry for that, but is there any solution where I can code something in my PHP files